# Cannot resolve symbol 'setStatusBarDisabled'?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a kiosk app to disable the navigation buttons and the status bar , but for whatever reason I'm getting "Cannot resolve symbol 'setStatusBarDisabled'" when I'm trying to call the function. (Check the picture below for a screen shot).

When I ctrl+click DevicePolicyManager and go to DevicePolicyManager.java I can see the function is there.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That statement is not inside a method. You cannot simply call methods in the class body, move this to a method, constructor or (static) initializer.